# Jackson adds wrapper for List

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have controller which returns an ArrayList of objects:

```
@GetMapping("/{access_token}/connected_instagram_accounts")
public ResponseEntity<List<InstagramAccountDTO>> getConnectedInstagramAccounts(@PathVariable("access_token") String accessToken) {
    log.debug("InstaramController.getConnectedInstagramAccounts() was called. access_token = {}", accessToken);

    List<InstagramAccountDTO> result = instagramService.getAllConnectedInstagramAccounts(accessToken);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In Postman i see that this endpoints returns following result:

```
{
    "ArrayList": []
}
```

But i expect that the ArrayList shouldn't have any wrapper object, and i'm expecting following result:

```
[]
```

I tried to check serialization in debugger and see that jackson serializes it in correct way.
[image]

Where do i need to look for the problem? What class is responsible for serializing **ResponseEntity**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually, it was my silly mistake. I have previously added following settings for jackson and forgot about it:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

So, it was the reason why jackson added wrapper object for my list.